# Is it possible for Tableau web column wrap text

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Is there a way with tableau web to wrap a column of text? I see in the desktop version it has that as an option but don't see it on my web client.

Comment: I don't think so, you still can't do everything in web that you can do in Desktop

Answer (score 1):

I just found out from the tableau website that it is not possible at the moment to wrap text with tableau online via the server release notes.